# Missing Google Play Services from AVD

Tags: android, google-play-services

I recently started developing for Android, and I have come into trouble when trying to use Google Maps in my app. I downloaded the Google Maps API v2 for Android, and have already performed all the required steps according to Google Developers Site.

My problem is that although the app runs, in the place where the maps should be displayed there is a texts saying that my device is missing Google Play Services.

I have already downloaded the Google Play Services from the SDK, imported the library into my project and also importing the .JAR file.

I am using Netbeans, not Eclipse, so many solutions I have found over the web aren`t useful for me. I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: There has got to be a thousand questions about using Google Maps on AVDs and one problem that I see a lot and had myself is that your target has to be set to "Google APIs (Google Inc.)" not something like "Android 2.2". Make sure you have that done before you worry about anything else.

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, you can't use the emulator to run apps that use Google Play services.  From http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html: *"Google Play services is not supported on the Android emulator — to develop using the APIs, you need to provide a development device such as an Android phone or tablet."*

Comment: So Location Controls in Emulator is useless! :j

Answer (score 12):

From google's own site http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

> If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for
>   Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and
>   install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform
>   target. Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google
>   APIs platform include Google Play services.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem and found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17873912/1627688):

Here are the updated [gms](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nhea18k7ic2gpb/com.google.android.gms-20130716.apk) and [vending](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hznsfc03shud2l9/com.android.vending-20130716.apk) files. Same instructions as before: Create a new emulator with any cpu/abi, a non google-api target (versions 10-17 work) and gpu emulation on or off, and then install the files:

```
adb install com.android.vending-20130716.apk 
adb install com.google.android.gms-20130716.apk
```

If you are upgrading an existing emulator then you might need to uninstall previous versions by:

```
adb uninstall com.android.vending
adb uninstall com.google.android.gms
```

Answer (score 1):

Bellow link contains a  solution that  works with Android 4.2.2 or higher

[How to install Google Play Services in Android Emulator](http://hintdesk.com/how-to-install-google-maps-in-android-emulator-and-use-it-in-intellij-idea/)

> 1.1 Start your emulator. Disconnect any other Android device (such as your smartphone) from computer.
> 1.2 Download these two files
>
> com.android.vending-19032013.apk : http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?7jfar2v1bzx6v59
> com.google.android.gms-19032013.apk : http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?4o9fz413uavlblf
>
> 1.3 Open command console, go to \platform-tools
>
> Install two files above with command
>
> adb install \com.android.vending-19032013.apk
> adb install \com.google.android.gms-19032013.apk

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Google maps on emulator. However, it's not officially supported, so takes some work. I had the best success following the info on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271933/2050917).

Answer (score 0):

I found this, i hope it helps you ;)

[Installing Google Play on Android Emulator](http://piotrbuda.eu/2012/05/installing-google-play-on-android-emulator.html)

[Run Google Play Services in your emulator](http://blog.apkudo.com/2012/08/08/run-google-play-on-an-emulator-and-pretend-to-be-any-device/)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still experiencing this issue, first try to create your emulator with the Google API's as the platform target. After doing so, I noticed that my Google Play Services was not the correct version on the emulator.

While trying to hack together a solution, I stumbled upon the `GoogleApiAvailability` class [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability). Google did a phenomenal job handling compatibility issues.

`GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context)` returns an integer status code, which can be fed directly into `getErrorDialog(Activity, errorCode, requestCode)` which returns a `Dialog` that works perfectly right out of the box. If your Play Services are out of date, the dialog will redirect you to an updater... If they are missing, it will redirect you to an installer, etc...

Thought I would share this great feature in case anyone is looking for a fix that would work in production code as well as testing.