# google map is not working on device as well as emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

i followed all the instructions in [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map).But after that when i started one project and try to run on emulator then it is displaying to update "This app wont run successfully unless you update google play services" and provided a update button and then when i am clicking the app is crashing.

In case of running in a device having 2.3.6 version in it, it throwing an exception and log is below:

Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:android.view.fragementin loader dalvik.system.Pathclassloader

. can anyone help here ?

Comment: share your piece of code and log cat that will be more help full to sort out problem
or try to change the Extend activity to Extend Fragment Activity This will solve your problem

Comment: There is no extra code.There is only code which is given as example in buttom of the link i have given in my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are trying to use fragments on a device that doesn't support this (without the support library).

There is one sentence in the link you gave:

> Please note that the code below is only useful for testing your settings in an application targeting Android API 12 or later

But your 2.3.x (cannot find a 2.3.6 version number in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)) is maximum API level 9.

Regarding the emulator: It doesn't run in emulator out-of-the-box. It is a bit tricky but there are some guys [who got it working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator).

Comment: Thanks for replying.But then why it is not working in emulator.Myh emulator is of level 17(latest)

Comment: thanks Matt i have not noticed these things in that link.BTW i wana know something.I am running in ubuntu as i know no driver is needed to be installed to connect a device and to see it in DDMS for ubuntu.But when i am conecting HTC Desire V,it displaying ?????? in DDMS not showing the details of device and also not taking the project to run on it. Any idea

Answer (score 0):

**Android tools --> Add Support libraries** 
 should solve the issue.

Comment: @ Android Killer : I would like to know few basic things . Did you add the permissions in the manifest file? Did you added the library project google-play-services_lib?

Comment: Yes i have already added all the permissions and also i imported project google-play-services_lib into eclipse and it is a library project and i have added this as reference into my project.So i think it is clear for you ?

Comment: public class YOURACTIVITY extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity