# Google Maps v2 doesn't work on Android Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have followed all steps from http://saleh360.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-running-google-maps-api-v2_12.html but I am not able to make google maps v2 work on android emulator.

When I run my project I get the message:
This app won't run unless you update Google Play services, along with the button "Update".
If I update, it takes me to the Google Play and cannot see the map of my application.

Moreover when I try to import "`<android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/maps`", I cannot locate the folder maps in my pc, although I got the latest version of Google play services

Has anyone else faced the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator

Answer (score 1):

I've created a (German) description how to get it working:

http://linuxchef.blogspot.de/2013/05/google-maps-api-v2-im-android-emulator.html

You basically need an emulator with at least API level 9 and no Google APIs. Then you'll have to get the APKs from a rooted device:

adb -d pull /data/app/com.android.vending-2.apk
adb -d pull /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk

and install them in the emulator:

adb -e install com.android.vending-2.apk
adb -e install com.google.android.gms-2.apk

You can even run the native Google Maps App, if you have an emulator with at least API level 14 and additionally install com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk

Have fun.

Comment: I have finally managed to see Google Maps v2 on emulator!! This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13869332#13869332 helped me and especially the two files: com.android.vending-20130711.apk and com.google.android.gms-20130711.apk that danbrough has attached.

Comment: If you have downloaded Google Play Services Rev.10, then please go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13869332#13869332 and download the two updated files that danbrough has attached: com.google.android.gms_20130908.apk and com.android.vending_20130908.apk. The emulator that I have created runs Android version 4.2.2.