# Google Maps for Android Apps Crash

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I created an application and tested it in an Android device. Now, when I try to test in an emulator, I get errors.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14562396/1652575), and [this](http://saleh360.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-running-google-maps-api-v2_12.html). They're the same, actually.

[This](http://pastebin.com/bTdjsXbV) is my LogCat. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use `<fragment>` from an activity that does not support fragments. The most likely case is that you are trying to use `SupportMapFragment` from an activity that does not inherit from `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Isn't that what [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) tells me to do?

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville: No. That page is having you use `<fragment>` for `MapFragment`, from a regular `Activity`, *on an API Level 12+ device*. You can tell that by reading the page you linked to, particularly: "Please note that the code below is only useful for testing your settings in an application targeting Android API 12 or later". You are attempting to run this on something running API Level 10 or older.

Comment: So, my problem is testing my code in an emulator with low level API? I just want to make my code work in API level 8 and above. What must I do? Isn't that 'getting started' page suitable for me?

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville: "So, my problem is testing my code in an emulator with low level API?" -- Maps V2 does not work in an emulator at the present time. "I just want to make my code work in API level 8 and above." -- then you will need to use `SupportMapFragment` in a `FragmentActivity`. "Isn't that 'getting started' page suitable for me?" -- the Maps V2 documentation assumes that readers have substantial Android application development experience and know the difference between the native API Level 11+ fragments and the Android Support package's backport of fragments.

Comment: So, do you have a learning page for me? I really am sorry about this. Just wanted to make things happen fast without really understanding them.

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville: "So, do you have a learning page for me?" -- not exactly. I have a series of sample apps that use `SupportMapFragment`, designed to accompany my book: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2

Comment: Thank you  very much. If I understand right, if I use SupportMapFragment, my app will work in API level 8+. And I can't test it in emulator. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville: "If I understand right, if I use SupportMapFragment, my app will work in API level 8+. And I can't test it in emulator." -- correct on both counts.