# why Google map api for android does not work on an AVD?

Tags: android, mobile, android-virtual-device

I'm developing a small android application where I want to display the google map in an avd (emulator). I'm using Android 2.3.3 and Eclipse Indigo.

The code is correct but when I run, I get an empty map. I'm wondering maybe the google map API for Android is not supported by the emulator.

if I want to test it, I have to buy a real phone?
I found a video tutorial where I guess avd is used. I'm not sure. I found also that it was an old version of API which no longer used.

Answer (score 1):

Google map v2 wont work in emulator.It's better test in phone.

[Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator)