# Android map API V2 Force Close

Tags: android

I want to make an Google Map App but i am getting Force close error. I had been already added the all permissions and Google play services etc. I also created a specific AVD for this but still i am getting Force Close error... So please Help Me.......:-)

This is my MainActivity.java file.

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
 private GoogleMap myMap;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
    = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();


   myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 }

}
```

This is my activity_main.xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Google_Map Manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.mapdemo"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
         <uses-permission 
            android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
         <uses-permission 
            android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
         <uses-permission 
            android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES">

         </uses-permission>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

            <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAjbIPh-1-2yzgbsjWMHHZM8MbD9c6hrbY"/>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: @Amit jayaswal - Are you testing your code in real device or emulator?

Answer (score 1):

You use twice :

```
<uses-permission 
            android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Try using :

```
<permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

In addition, you can't test google map api V2 on Android emulator :
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

> Note: Google Play services is not supported on the Android emulator — to develop using the APIs, you need to provide a development device such as an Android phone or tablet.

You must test your code on a real device. If you haven't any device, you can test this unofficial solution : [Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator/14271933#14271933)

Answer (score 0):

**Try changing:**

`class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>`

**to**

`class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>`

It worked for me.