# Google Map V2 on Android Emulator

Tags: android

When Implement Google Map API, I got blank screen and these logs :

Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices

Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings

I think I have problem with my key. Because when I change the key. I still got the same log above. I got my key with SHA1.
This is my manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="abcdef"/>
    </application>

     </manifest>
```

This is my logs :

```
05-10 15:57:00.460: E/ActivityThread(1168): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-10 15:57:00.480: E/ActivityThread(1168): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-10 15:57:00.670: D/dalvikvm(1168): GC_CONCURRENT freed 300K, 3% free 11260K/11591K, paused 80ms+4ms, total 145ms
05-10 15:57:00.670: D/dalvikvm(1168): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
05-10 15:57:00.780: E/ActivityThread(1168): Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
05-10 15:57:00.790: E/ActivityThread(1168): Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
```

Comment: upgrade to v3 google v2 is outdated

Comment: @RachelGallen can you post the link to support the same.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro. and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/ api v1 is depreceated

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Mobile

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: @RachelGallen does that hold good for android coz api v2 works for me

Comment: @user2369323 test the app on real  device

Comment: Android Maps API v2 is now designated as a native implementation of Google Maps for Android--> Which is not work in Emulator and Google Maps v3 is webview (javascript) based which is work in webview--->https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Mobile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Google Map V2 on Android Emulator

Maps V2 is not supported on emulators at the present time.

Comment: Are Map v2 on emulators supported now ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.  I installed, verified and posted this msg within 15-minutes.

See duplicate question here:
[Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator)

After installation, Google Maps v2 was correctly working on my emulator image.  One slight wrinkle that I discovered (perhaps non-issue) was that running an emulator image with Google APIs returned "Failed: Already Installed" when attempting to install the two required APKs.  Selecting the same SDK version, without Google APIs, and then manually installing the two required APKs succeeded and the Maps were visible.

Happy Mapping.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, referencing the **Google Android Map Api v2** you can't run google maps v2 on Android emulator; you must use a device for your tests.

but if you do not have the real testing device or phone you can do this below

You need to try on an emulator with the Google API's version. Each Platform has two versions Android and Android+Google APIs.

Ensure that when you create the AVD, you select on target field the Google APIs version.

And this can be also helpful: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

Following are the steps that I am listing below to enable Google Maps on your android

Create a new emulator

- for device choose "5.1'' WVGA (480 x 800: mdpi)
- for target choose "Android 4.1.2 - API level 16
- for "CPU/ABI" choose ARM
- leave rest to defaults

these are the settings that are working for me. I don't know for different ones.

Start the emulator

install [com.android.vending-1.apk](http://www.filedropper.com/comandroidvending-1)  and [com.google.android.gms-1.apk](http://www.filedropper.com/comgoogleandroidgms-1) via ADB install command

Google Maps should work now in your emulator. Please comment is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

in this case check your play services manifest file and check the version code for apk file com.google.android.gms. in the below it is "3136110" .download these apk files and install from dos prompt but before installation run your target emulator.

```
 package="com.google.android.gms"
android:versionCode="3136110"
android:versionName="3.1.36 (673201-10)
```

i am giving a link http://ge.tt/9x9n4lg from which i got these apk files,hope it will help you

Comment: @CommonsWare it is possible to test google mep v2 on emulator. i successively run it on emulator. this is simple and easy just install apk files to emulator.