# Developing a google play app with HTC Desire

Tags: eclipse, google-play, google-maps-android-api-2, android

I've been a Java developer for 6 years, but this is my first foray into Android, and it's not going well.

I've set up a simple example app which uses google maps api v2 - it's just a single page: I copied it from one of the many helpful sites on this topic.

I then discovered that I can't run it in an emulator since it uses the google maps api v2, which requires google play. So I bought a device (HTC Desire).

Now the device doesn't show up in the eclipse run configuration. It shows up with ./adb devices just fine.

I thought maybe this was because the device is on Android 2.2, and my app has minimum OS level of 4.2. So I tried to upgrade, but I couldn't work out how. In the software / update section on the phone it just says 'no updates available'. Can this be right?

Ok so assuming I can't upgrade the OS (in which case the phone is now useless), I modified the project so the minSdkVersion is now 8. But now my project won't build!

Errors include 'No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'' - what does that even mean?

And to cap it all the device is now doing the 'buzzing 7 times instead of booting' thing. I can access some menu called HBOOT, and selecting RECOVERY just reboots the machine, which fails.

So now I've spent £50 and several hours, and I haven't even got as far as hello world - just a bricked phone.

What am I doing wrong? Can Android dev really be this hard?

Comment: 'I then discovered that I can't run it in an emulator since it requires google play.'.....what does that mean??......u dont need google play to run ur apps on emulator...!!!...Are u sure u r using the Eclipse IDE...i was developing android apps using emulator till i bought a phone recently.....

Comment: IF the updates are not available for your phone try Custom Mods like CyanogenMod....make sure u do it carefully...

Comment: Android Development is as cool as Breeze....u just need to be informed and stay enthusiastic..!!

Comment: According to several people, the 'Google Android Map Api v2'is not supported on an emulator.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478801/

Comment: Try an actual "Hello World" by generating a default project in Eclipse.  That should clear up whether the problem has to do with your phone or your software.  The sample you selected appaarently requires a 4.2+ API, and there's a reason for that.  If you want to run it on lower API levels you'll have to add some reflection code to test available interfaces and code around them if they're missing in an earlier version of the OS.  That's more complicated than you need right now.