# Where do I get Google Play Services 3136100

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to use Google map in a very simple app. I get as a warning that Google Play Service is out-of-date and that 3136100 is required. This is only a warning but my application does not show any map. I get again a button to click on it to update Google Play Service and when I click on it I get a Fatal exception:

```
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.bb$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-03 06:28:07.472: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

enter code here

So what can I do to see a map with my application? How do I update Google Play Service?

Comment: You can find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17036337/902217

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to update from the SDK Manager 
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

If that still doesn't work try these files...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vel9hag6toked7/com.android.vending.apk 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xt8ls9ov7s36rcw/com.google.android.gms.apk

and install: Instructions taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17036337/996364 (would've just linked you there but found the files before I found that thread)

Open the AVD

Execute this in the terminal / cmd

adb -e install com.google.android.gms.apk 
adb -e install com.android.vending.apk

Restart the AVD

If the problem is only on your device and not the emulator update play services from the device (but I think there's a newer version than what you need now so don't know how that'll work)

Comment: Is there exists some official page with this libraries?

Comment: No, but updating from the sdk manager is official.. same with updating phone... and since your error seems to be a couple versions back the sdk manager should fix your problem... I'm guessing that everyone posting files like these are grabbing them from their phone or somewhere similar

Comment: @CAMOBAP That first link IS to the official sdk site... and has info on how to test if the device your app is running on is updated and if it's not how to give users the option to update

Answer (score 0):

you can check this blog post for different versions of Google Play services libraries:

http://venomvendor.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/android-sdk-extras-by-google-inc.html

Comment: Is there exists some official page with this libraries?