# Google map api v2 shows blank screen with only zoom buttons on emulator

Tags: android

**Solution** The problem was caused by Google Maps Android API v2 not being supported on emulator. Using a real device for testing solved the problem.

**Question** I am trying for google map, I got API key from Google. But when I run an  application it shows blank white screen with zoom buttons

Here is my code -  MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my XML file - activity_main.XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment 
         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is Manifest.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demogooglemapv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
         android:name="com.example.demogooglemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission  android:name="com.example.demogooglemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
         android:required="true"/>       
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data 
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB2jvxyj-WbkYc1Y1WR9Sc1E1W22QywA_k"
            />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.demogooglemapv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you given the app permission to access internet?

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: put your AndroidManifest.xml. which will help developer to find out a problem.

Comment: Also, make sure you enabled the service for "Google Maps Android API v2", and not for "Google Maps API v2"

Comment: @Josnidhin yeah i given access internet permission in manifest file

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli  i edited my question by adding manifest file ... now please help me . i stucked up from last 3 days

Comment: Try moving the meta-data tag to just before application tag closes.

Comment: @Josnidhin  i tried but still same problem .. now what should i do ?

Comment: try this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: @Josnidhin i already followed this link . but did not got any solution.

Comment: @AndyRes  i already enable "Google Maps Android API v2 " and not for "Google Maps API v2" .. But did not get any success ..

Comment: Check the following. Do you have any errors in logcat? Did you create the API key for your debug certificate?

Comment: @Josnidhin i checked logcat . i found this error "Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above"  Now what should i do ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32932/discussion-between-josnidhin-and-shweta-jain)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Google Maps v2 on Android Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generate maps key with debug/release key-store Where the APK will be build.

Comment: how can i generate maps key with debug/release key-store ? please tell me procedure ..

Comment: this may help you... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#displaying_certificate_information

Answer (score 2):

To generate map api key with debug keystore follow this.Try this with command prompt

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin\keytool.exe -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\android3\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

Note:debug.keystore path will be change for you from
`C:\Users\android3\.android\debug.keystore` by default debugkeystore is present in `.android` folder

Comment: i already get MD5 and SHA-1 key with this command ..  i followed this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: use SHA-1 key for map v2 with my experience MD5 key does not work in map api v2

Comment: yes i used SHA-1 key for get API key for map v2 .. last year i used MD5 key for map v1...

Comment: did you try it on real device?

Comment: now i checked on real device with 4.2.2 version . its working fine ... thanxx @Deen

Comment: if u accept the answer also upvote it. else its just discouraging to help you again

Comment: it is because your emulator doesn't have google play service so only it display blank screen anyway welcome shweta

Comment: @Deen how can i install google play services on emulater ? please suggest me

Comment: you need to install Extra services to sdk manager refer this http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: @Deen I already do this . And also add library in my project ...and also check isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() method . it resturns success . it means google play serivces is installed in my emulater .

Comment: i found this error "Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above" Now what should i do ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32942/discussion-between-deen-and-shweta-jain)

Answer (score 0):

I find that if initially you happened to submit the androidManifest wrong.
and once you corrected it and you verified that the 
It helps to remove your app from your device and let it install again from your IDE.
somehow Android does cache that info.

Comment: Please make sure to answer the question, or indicate why your answer is the correct steps.  It doesn't appear that you read and understood the question.