# Google maps isn't loading a map in my app

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Before I start I am very new to using java I usually produce app is with flash, but someone told me that eclipse is better so I am a beginner when it comes to eclipse and android.

I am trying to produce a basic navigation style app using Google maps. I followed countless tutorials and googled for hours to try and solve my problem but I have found nothing.

The problem is that the map doesn't load in it just shows a grid of grey rectangles. I can't see any errors myself but I don't where to look. I have generated the API key for google maps for my certificate and by debug keystore as countless tutorials and topics on here suggest.
[Link 1](http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/how-to-get-google-maps-api-key-for-android-issues-and-errors-solved/)

I used this method for SHA1 key. I have tried debugging this in the emulator, on a device and exporting the apk file and installing directly onto my device.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.route1designs.tenttom"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.route1designs.tenttom.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
        <activity android:label="mainmenu" android:name="MainMenu"></activity>  
        <activity android:label="settings" android:name="Settings"></activity> 

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.route1designs.tenttom.AIzaSyCAL-boLUdqDM_fLwlewYKNWHReXYVoEdU"
    android:value="AIzaSyCAL-boLUdqDM_fLwlewYKNWHReXYVoEdU"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

my mainMenu(map activity):

```
package com.route1designs.tenttom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;


import com.route1designs.dbfunctions.DatabaseHandler;
import com.route1designs.dbfunctions.Location;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.List;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainMenu extends MapActivity {

    //adds page vars for default page
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mc;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.start_map);

             mc = mapView.getController();

            String coordinates[] = {"30", "71"};
             double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
             double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

             GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
             (int) (lat * 1E6),
             (int) (lng * 1E6));

             mc.animateTo(p);
             mc.setZoom(7);
             mapView.invalidate();


            //build vars
            currentLocBG = findViewById(R.id.currentLoc);
            currentLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentLocText);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        onMenuPressed();
        return true;

    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }       

}
```

And this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/start_map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyBp9PQhSJxHiJcRm6wETHbZr-eXcICanvI"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as am completely stuck. If there is nothing that can be done is it easier to incorporate google maps into flash professional or builder.

Comment: i guess you are using map api v1 which is deprecated. use map api v2

Comment: How would I switch that

Comment: you are using map api v1 follow the steps here. use map api v2. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: @Raghunandan you were right the problem was I was using V1 instead of V2. After a little bit of googleing I came accross this [site][1]


  [1]: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/

which explains how to use the google maps V2 for android. Its not a great deal of difference but it does make a bit more sense now. I have noticed that a few people have had this problem this could be the reason why.

Comment: there is no need to go through tutorials. i could get the map working using the docs. Has all the details necessary. the map api v1 is deprecated.

Comment: I have got it working now, I used a tutorial to set up the V2 version the rest is pretty straight forward thanks for your help. I would close the question but it won't let me for another 6 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running on the emulator or on a real device? Google Maps API v2 will not run in emulator that have been created with target "Google APIs", this is a known issue. See [Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator) for a workaround

Comment: I am running on both, I have tried the link above to use api V2 but still unsuccessful

Comment: I then suggest you start with the [Google Getting Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) and see how far you can get with their example. If the map is still not showing it will be helpful to have a look at your LogCat output.

Comment: Yeah that solved the problem all the documentation tells you everything you need to know. Thanks everyone