# Getting message on AVD "This app won't work unless you update Google play services"

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I want to add google map in my android app. After following all the steps and removing exceptions such as "inflating class fragment", my AVD is now showing `This app won't work unless you update Google play services`. I tried to update Google play services through the following steps

Right click on Project > Android Tools > Add Support Library

But got 2 error messages.

```
    [2013-08-08 09:36:00 - SDK Manager]   Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Connection to http://10.10.10.100:8080 refused
[2013-08-08 09:37:45 - SDK Manager]   Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml, reason: HttpHostConnect Connection to http://10.10.10.100:8080 refused
```

I am using the emulator Eclipse version 4.2.0
`manifest.xml` file is attached here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

       <permission
        android:name="com.example.newapp.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.newapp.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.newapp.NewApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="*********************************" />
           </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_new_app.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".NewApp" >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout
```

>
NewApp.java

```
package com.example.newapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class NewApp extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_app);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_app, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: Latest versions of Google Maps can't be run in emulator as it doesn't have Google Play services installed.

Comment: @user2012, But Google map is available as a separate application in my emulator.

Comment: :To run v2 Map, **Google Play Services** must be installed not Google Map.

Comment: possible duplicate of [This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services. (via Bazaar)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Android Map Api v2 doc says,you can't run google maps v2 on Android emulator. You must use a device for your tests. But some people suggest it can be done by installing the required services like `Google Play Services` in the emulator. See the various answers of the following post, you will get some clue.

[Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator)