# How to run Google Map API V2 on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-maps-android-api-2

I've tried to implement Google Maps v2 in my Android Application, but unfortunately instead of Maps I can see this message:

> This app won't run without Google Play Services, which are missing from your phone along with button "Get Google Play Services".

Before tell me, is this possible to run Google Maps on Android emulator?

Comment: thanks Aravinth, but how to install google play services in emulator, i have successfully install com.google.gms.apk and com.google.vendig.apk on emulator, but it will not work.

Comment: browse and get the google play apk and then install in your emulator.

Comment: Just refer this one you can get some idea.

[Google maps on emulator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator?rq=1

Comment: i have also tried this, but i am not able to install google plak apk, emulator is always get force close browser dialogue.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator?rq=1

Comment: refer this http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/07/google-map-android-api-v2-with-location.html

Answer (score 5):

You should use an emulator based on SDK version 4.2.2 or higher. Look here for details:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

> Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services.

Comment: as i know there is no a legal possibility to install google play onto an emulator less than 4.2

Comment: also look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14537079/968702 maybe ot couyld be useful for u

Answer (score 2):

Try [Genymotion emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/)....It supports location based services.

Comment: my pc configuration is not supported to genymotion, can you please suggest me another way. i have tried oracle virtual box and emulator.

Comment: Same with me, my PC too does not support Genymotion.So i can not test google maps on my android emulator. I have to use my phone instead.

Comment: means u don't have solution rather than real device?

Answer (score 2):

you can select as the target api as google api.It support maps I have also tried it & it successfully running.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Genymotion emulator and test your google map api
.
http://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes some people suggests its possible to run Google Map in Emulator to by installing `google play services`.Check the below post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18119265/1665507