# Unfortunately application has stopped using google map api v2 for android

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried from three days but my problem is not resolved!, I was making an app using Google API maps v2, I activated it successfully...

Now when I run my program it's showing this error: "Unfortunately, apps has stopped"

please help what kind of error is this ??

Here is a manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCKewNqqmmp2gwcLuefCAXrTRdQjm-6t-U" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a MainActivity:

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

SupportMapFragment mMap;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    googleMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager() //Now, here showing an error "cannot convert from SupportMapFragment to GoogleMap" and can't run this program.
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map).getMap();
  }
}
```

Here is a log cat file:

```
02-19 05:08:50.393: I/Process(1405): Sending signal. PID: 1405 SIG: 9
02-19 05:15:42.608: E/dalvikvm(1447): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method com.example.maps.MainActivity.onCreate
02-19 05:15:42.608: E/dalvikvm(1447): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method com.example.maps.MainActivity.onCreate
02-19 05:15:42.608: W/dalvikvm(1447): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 728 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;) in Lcom/example/maps/MainActivity;
02-19 05:15:42.696: D/dalvikvm(1447): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0012
02-19 05:15:43.308: D/AndroidRuntime(1447): Shutting down VM
02-19 05:15:43.308: W/dalvikvm(1447): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4be8648)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maps/com.example.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.example.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     ... 11 more
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     ... 21 more
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.maps-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.maps-2, /system/lib]]
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
02-19 05:15:43.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     ... 24 more
02-19 05:15:53.760: I/Process(1447): Sending signal. PID: 1447 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It's seems like you have not added `google_play_servies.lib` into your project.

Comment: I added it succesfully ...

Comment: Make sure you have added the `android-supportv4` library in your project. It should not be taking reference from another project.

Comment: are u running ur application on emulator?

Comment: I added it into `Reference Library` as a API using Eclipse..

Comment: @Monika Yes using Genymotion..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459338/how-to-run-google-map-api-v2-on-android-emulator

Comment: I'm using aandroid 4.4..and Genymotion as a Emulator

Comment: Here is a pic which i added play service as into Refernce library http://postimg.org/image/ok101s8kt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you should inflate your map in `GoogleMap` which is already itself have now became `Fragment` besides that your are inflating it into `SupportMapFragment`.

Change your below lines :

```
 mMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    googleMap = mMap.getMap();
```

To as below:

```
 googleMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map).getMap();
```

Use the instance of `GoogleMap` not the `SupportMapFragment`. As if you will use `SupportMapFragment` it will always go for searching the for the class which you have defined for that `Fragment` in your layout. And will search for the method of `getMap()`, Which is the method of `GoogleMap` class only.

**EDITED:**

Make sure the below libraries are there in your projects.

Add play-services-libs as project.
[image]

And Add library in build path.

[image]

Comment: I tried but it's giving an error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from SupportMapFragment to GoogleMap"

Comment: Try to clean your project and then check. Make sure you have added the library `android-support-v4.jar` in your project's build path.

Comment: I Cleaned, now it's showing "Open Declaration com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment


Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.
"

Comment: Is your jar file inside your projects libs folder ?

Comment: Add this lines `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in your manifest file inside `<application>` tag.

Comment: are you talking about `Google play service`?? here is a pic ..http://postimg.org/image/ok101s8kt/ it is into `Reference Library`

Comment: Noopp i am talking about the `android-support-v4.jar` file. which should be in your libs folder.

Comment: `android-support-v4.jar` is inside `Android Private Libraries` and your Manifest file i tried this but still not responding..

Comment: @user3326455 Please update your question with your latest error.

Comment: Unfortunately, maps has stopped.

Comment: Try out to get your map using the code `googleMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map).getMap();` @user3326455 It should work now. If doesn't then update your question with latest error.

Comment: Is there a `google-play-services_lib.jar` added in your project ?

Comment: i added `Google-play-services` **project->properties->java build path->Libraries->add external library(went to sdk path extras->google(folder)->google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib‌​\libs) then added this library...** i followed that instruction to import Google-play-services!!

Comment: That library should be copied into your workspace. Otherwise it will not properly reference it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah i got it after Vogella tutorial ....while i added it not through your process...But when i import it through "Import" ..it shows nothing...help!

Comment: What are you saying? @user3326455 I didn't get you.

Comment: You were right i hadn't imported successfully, I'm learning it from youtube....thanks for paying time :)

Comment: You're Welcome !! :) Glad that helped you. All the Best :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Google map in emulator see this step by step process which I answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372399/running-google-map-application-on-android-emulator/19407415#19407415) previous question

Comment: But i'm using "Genymotion" as an Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**First change** in `xml` change this line

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

to

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

**2nd change** in `manifest` add this inside `application tag`

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

> Most important u have add `google-play-sevice-lib` into ur project like this

[image]
**check ur `API-Key` is generated in `Google console` with ur computer's SHA-1;ur package name**

### EDIT :

How to `import` the `google_play_services_lib` Make Sure `ur project and library present in same worksapce` [image]

Comment: I added `google-play-sevice-lib` inside `Reference Library` because when i import it like you ..it shows nothing after pressing "Add" as you prvided a pic

Comment: @user3326455 : make sure when u importing `play-service-lib` u copied that into `same workspace` after that add that library into `ur project`

Comment: i added `Google-play-services` **project->properties->java build path->Libraries->add external library(went to sdk path extras->google(folder)->google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs) then added this library...** i followed that instruction to import `Google-play-services`!!

Comment: not like that u have to import `whole project` into eclipse and `don't forget to check the copy projects into workspace` then add that as library into ur project

Answer (score 0):

the sure shot solved answer for **unfortunately the app stopped** error during implementing google play services api are:

main Activity:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

instead of

```
 import android.location.LocationListener;
```

use these in dependencies:(build gradle file)

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Android manifest file:

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```