# Error while setting the marker listener on Google map in android api 10

Tags: android, google-maps, exception, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add the marker listener by implementing the **OnMarkerClickListener** and setting **googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((OnMarkerClickListener)this)**

It is working fine with the actual device but giving the **NullPointerException** error on the emulator. It is also working fine with the device with api 19, but Why is this happening with emulator.

I am using the SupportMapFragment for displaying the map.

Here is the code

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.orderlayout);

    Log.i(TAG, "Started order onCreate method Activity");

    status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        // Success! Do what you want

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setTitle("Debugging");
        ad.setMessage("Error getting the GooglePlayServicesUtilities");
        ad.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //comeHome();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
        AlertDialog dialog = ad.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    // Setting the map features
    mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    gMap = mMapFragment.getMap();

    // set the click listeners for the marker in map
    try{
    gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((OnMarkerClickListener) this);
    }catch(Exception e){Log.v(TAG,"Error setting the click listener for the marker: "+e.toString());}


    try {
        gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buzz",
                "Error with the current location button" + e.toString());
    }
    LatLng latLng = getCurrentLocation(this);

    Log.v(TAG,latLng.latitude+latLng.longitude+"");
    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position( new LatLng(latLng.latitude,
              latLng.longitude)).title("Your Current Location"));

    try {

        gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buzz",
                "Error while enabling the current location" + e.toString());
    }
```

}

@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker)
    {
        return false;
    }

and My Logcat is:

```
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{blr.infovita.buzzpharma/blr.infovita.buzzpharma.OrderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at blr.infovita.buzzpharma.OrderActivity.onCreate(OrderActivity.java:278)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-17 12:15:50.119: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is your logcat said????? post some code...

Comment: try{
  gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((OnMarkerClickListener) this);
  }catch(Exception e){Log.v(TAG,"Error setting the click listener for the marker: "+e.toString());} this returns with the NullPointerException

Comment: post your all code with logcat in your question.....

Comment: Paste the error logs from Logcat

Comment: guys it is giving null pointer exception in emulator but working fine in real device

Comment: what is OrderActivity.java line 278?

Comment: gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener( this); <-- this line, which is giving the NullPointerException

Comment: I guess GoogleMap wont work in emulator, you need real time device to work. May be this will help [Maps on Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459338/how-to-run-google-map-api-v2-on-android-emulator).

Comment: @bharat yes Bharat it is working fine on the real device, i was testing with the emulator