# Google API v2 not work on Emulator

Tags: android

I followed all the steps from :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

and i got this error when im trying to start application. I used android 2_2 emulator
Whats wrong ?

[2013-10-22 08:32:44 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger
[2013-10-22 08:32:45 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8627 for debugger

Comment: test it on a real deivce

Comment: Is that an error or a warning? I often get a warning message like that.

Comment: hope this will help u.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator

Comment: google map is part of google play services.  Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services. so test it on a device

Answer (score 0):

Google Map runs in Emulator  by installing google play services.Check the below post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18119265/1665507

Answer (score 0):

**It works only in 4.2.2 or up version emulator!**

please check below link -

[This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services (via Bazaar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window > Preferences > Android > DDMS

Check "Use ABDHOST" and leave the value as 127.0.0.1
[image]

Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Google API v2 map is only work in 4.2.2 or up version in emulator. For more information regarding Google API v2 visit this [link.](http://dhruvvaishnav.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-google-map-v2.html)