# this app won't run unless you update google play services . [May be Duplicated]

Tags: android, android-mapview

I tried to create a simple app with google map using GG API key v2

I follow exactly everything in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

but i still get this error

[image]

I already tried to fixed and i also read some topic in this forum ( may be my question is duplicated) . But i stll dont know how to fix it

Comment: if you have read this question before and you allready suspect it is a duplicate, why post it? It'll be hard to gain the reputation needed for posting images (for instance) like that?

Comment: Run your project in Real device and update your google play services library.

Answer (score 3):

From the link you provided, it seems that you are attempting to run Google Maps API v2 on an emulator. 
This is currently not officially supported - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118149/getting-message-on-avd-this-app-wont-work-unless-you-update-google-play-servic/18119265#18119265) for more details.

Nevertheless, some SO users have created an emulator that does support it. I suggest reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937) and attempting their method.