# Error in display map (Google play services )

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using google map V2 in my application android , I try for the first time to display the map ,I followed the official Tutorial , but i have this error

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOReI.png “Google Play services, which some of your applications rely on, is not supported by your device.”  and google play services is well installed  http://d.pr/i/CPX2 "AVD" 
PS: I'm using emulator API15

Comment: Test it on real device as Google Play Services application is required to be installed on real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the API key , I'm sure you have a problem there

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the emulator in a easier way because to use Google Maps API in an app the phone needs to be registered in Google Play. Follow this  tutorial to test in emulator: http://saleh360.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/android-running-google-maps-api-v2_12.html

Answer (score 1):

Try it in a physical device rather than the AVD. To run maps V2 on your physical device you should have the updated version of google maps and google play services.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use emulator. It doesn't have Google play services. Test in Real device. If you want to test in emulator, follow this. [Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator) by Panini Luncher.