# Running google map application on Android Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-emulator

My application uses Google Maps v2. This application successfully working on Android powered device. I tried to run the same application on Android emulator. The target of my emulator is `Google APIs API Level 18` but the problem here is application runs on the emulator but map is not drawing on the map fragment, please see the image below
[image]

In the logcat I can see following error

```
Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
```

and the following warning

```
eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

I have added this feature in Manifest

```
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Does anybody have an idea how to run this simple application on the emulator ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have written a tutorial about how to get Google Maps up and running on emulator devices. http://twntee.tumblr.com/post/59576020346/the-maps-api-adding-a-map-to-your-android-project, have a look it may help you.

Comment: Duplicate?: [Map not getting in emulator android api v2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19094787/456814).

Answer (score 11):

I got finally map in my emulator. I followed these steps to achieve it.

1. Create avd and start emulator
2. Go to platform tools path present in Android SDK and put these apk's in it.

   - com.android.vending-20130716
   - com.google.android.gms-20130716
3. Install these apk's one by one by going to platform tools path by using command prompt(shift+Right click-->open command window here).Follow these commands

   - adb devices
   - adb install com.android.vending-20130716
   - adb install com.google.android.gms-20130716
4. Import google-play-services_lib project which is present at project location and add it to your project.
5. Restart emulator and clean your project and run it through emulator.

That's it. :)
you can download above apk's from following link

[Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Android 4.4, it is now possible to run Google Maps in the Android emulator, even with Intel HAXM AVD.  No need to run anything on the adb command anymore.  It takes several steps, though.  I created a series of videos on the subject, if it helps.  I use a JSON feed to put markers on a map in a 4.4 emulator.  They are about 30 minutes each, so you may want to skip ahead to find what you want.  The first two videos are the most relevant for this question.   I have three more videos in the series that deal with JSON and markers... see my YouTube channel for those.

1) Using Google Maps in Android Emulator (general setup and prereqs)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gT-kORiFRTo
2) Show maps in Android emulator https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MZIYkm3Ezg

Thanks and good luck!

Brandan

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have internet access

and the  the following permission in your manifest:  `

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<!--
```

The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    
    
`

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps v2 requires Google Play Services , it's not available in Android emulator. You can try this blog post , should be helpful for you.

http://javamvp.blogspot.com/2013/06/put-android-maps-v2-work-on-your.html

If map loading is the only issue you have then I am pretty sure that its api key issue. Please recheck that in manifest.

Comment: This is not correct according to the documentation it is available see this "If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform target.

Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services."

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: If they have included it in recent version, then the above setup is not needed. It was not available previously. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google map can not load in emulator.

You need to install application in real device.

Or optionally you can use Bluestack and test your application in it.

http://bluestacks.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. To display Google map in the emulator, you can use a "browser key" from google developer console, instead of the  Android key.This is because the android key is private therefore will only display the map on a real device, however by using a browser key, in your manifest file , you can run your map on an android emulator. To create a browser key goto "https://code.google.com/apis/console/" , for the website, leave it blank and just click create. Use the generated key in your manifest file an this should display the map.
2. I also suggest you use install gene-motion emulator, download and install google play services  on it and you will be good to go.

Comment: can anyone confirm this use of "browser key" is a valid workaround for testing? The [doc page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup) says "You need an Android API key, not a browser key.".