# Google Play Services error in android emulator (eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, emulation

Hey I've been trying since a week now to get the maps thing working on Eclipse. I downloaded all the necessary packages and did everything that they've asked to on the "getting started" page on google's developer site that is meant for developing using Google Maps. But when I run the code in the emulator it tells me, "Google play services is not supported by your device"

[image: Here is the error]

Need some help guys as to what to do. Please do let me know about any suggestions.

Comment: Just some additional info that I felt I left out.
Running an emulator with API level 17 (4.2.2)

Comment: Set the emulator's platform to Google APIs instead of Android.

Comment: Play store service never  work in emulator...

Comment: @user3211841 : it wont run unless you sign your app by valid keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can get Google map V2 in emulator too. I got it please refer this step by step procedure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372399/running-google-map-application-on-android-emulator/19407415#19407415) link which I answered in previous question.

Answer (score -1):

To work with Google Map API v2, you are required to have Google Play services enabled device.

To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:

- A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
- The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

**Update:**

I would suggest you to give [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator a try.

Comment: But I read somewhere that with some update google let emulators run google play services...

Comment: Hey, I am using an emulator that is running with Android API 4.2.2. On the advice of a fellow user here I switched it to Google API 4.2.2 and now the error message I get is that "This app wont run unless you update Google Play Services". This is weird because my Google Play Services is up to date, just checked! Any tips?