# How to run Google Maps in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

My CPU is Intel i5-3470 processor, and I'm trying to run Google Maps in the Android emulator with steps mentioned in that various blogs and wikis. All blogs/wikis says to create a emulator with the ARM processor.

When I'm trying to create an emulator, that option is disabled, and so I cannot change the processor information in the Android emulator creation step. Is there a way to create an emulator of such configuration, and is it possible to run Google Maps in the Android 
Emulator with i5 as my processor?

Answer (score 3):

The Google Android Map API is not able to run Google Maps on the Android emulator. You must use an Android device for testing your app.

In another case, if you still want to use it through: then it requires installation of separate APK files into the emulator image. Use *[Google Maps on Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372399/running-google-map-application-on-android-emulator)*.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now. You have to create a AVD using "Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)"