# Unfortunately app has stopped working on Android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, inflate-exception

I've already tried Jack instructions but I'm still getting this error

I've posted new logcat below

```
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335): Unable to install secure provider, due to exception:
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335): java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10007 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1914)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1943)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:600)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at com.google.android.gsf.e.c(SourceFile:107)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.insertProviderGated(SourceFile:90)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at com.google.android.gms.common.app.GmsApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:85)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4556)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-28 21:10:08.603: A/GmsApplication(3335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335): Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 3335
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10007 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2774)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10007 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1914)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1943)
05-28 21:10:08.940: E/AndroidRuntime(3335):     ... 9 more
05-28 21:10:16.483: E/libEGL(934): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-28 21:10:16.483: E/SurfaceFlinger(934): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1395899833
05-28 21:10:16.483: E/SurfaceFlinger(934): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
```

Comment: Define your MainActivity  in menifest

Comment: Post your layout file.

Comment: post your marifest file.

Comment: You should try and post some info on how the error actually came about. It's sometimes hard to tell from errors what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 2):

The exception details are clearly mentioned in the logcat like

```
 The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7327000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Change your manifest `meta-data` tag according to the above details.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but can you help me again? Im getting new error

Comment: You have to create emulator with google api(google play services) to work it...or you can use the real device...

Comment: My emulator used android api not the google api, i'll try your advice

Answer (score 0):

insert your manifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Yourclassname"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>




    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="7327000" />
```

Comment: already insert that, and still getting error like I've posted above

Comment: im created emulator using android api

Comment: download this apk "com.android.vending.apk" and this one "com.google.android.gms.apk" use cmd prom-pat to instal the apk files then run your project on emulater.

Comment: follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372399/running-google-map-application-on-android-emulator

Comment: http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2012/12/06/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/

Comment: Im getting new error after follow your instructions, i've posted the new logcat above

Comment: errors occurred in this class pls check  at com.google.android.gms.common.app.GmsApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:85)

Answer (score 0):

You must have the following 
 declaration within the AndroidManifest. Xml

```
<application> element: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

It is said in the logcat

Comment: Can you post your java file

Comment: try to run the project  real device

Comment: here is my java file https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3yzzb2vj5623vb/MGIS29.rar?dl=0 @user4847410

Comment: @Jack the problem is, i dont have that real device