# Can't display current location in map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

I want to display current location in map. for that I found [this article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android)

this is my whole activity:

```
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static final String TAG = MainMapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "oncreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }


}
```

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "APP ID"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

and in manifest I have permissions:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    </application>
```

When I run application in emulator it shows empty map. I'm pretty new at android so wont be surprised if there's any error.

First thing I thought was that I must call `handleNewLocation` method in `onMapReady` but there I can't pass latlong parameter (?)

Comment: have you used google api emulator

Comment: @Ajinkya not. can you explain in more details?

Comment: See that blog link you given again he used Google api arm EABI emulator try to use that

Answer (score 0):

As I know, android emulator or genymotion emulator is not able to run Google Maps by default. I don't know which emulator you are using. For native emulator, follow [Google Map on Native Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372399/running-google-map-application-on-android-emulator)

On genymotion you don't have google play services installed, so activity with google map will simply crash. To install google play services on genymotion,  follow this link: [Google map on genymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su)

But, it's better to simply use your physical device for map related things.

Comment: I'm using Nexus 5 android studio native emulator.. it displays markers if i'll do it manually but I want to insert current location that's the problem

Comment: I tested your code and it is working fine on my physical device. In physical device I have to enable location for using gps to track my device's location. I hope you are doing that in your emulator too.