# How to run google maps on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, emulation, genymotion

How to run google maps on emulator. I had not been able to do so, because the solutions gave in similar cuestion included files obsoletes, and are limited to some specifics configurations that does not meet my requirements.

Comment: Duplicate?: [Map not getting in emulator android api v2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19094787/456814).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After three days of reading tons and tons of tutorial on how to do this, this is the UP-TO-DATE solution with the UP-TO-DATE files and EASIEST steps to follow.

Steps.
1. Install genymotion emulator (This is way much faster than the eclipse emulator). All about it is easier. Research on how to start it.

2. Download these three apk's ()
3. Go to the platform tools folder of your adt bundle instalation folder (your_root_to_your_sdk\sdk\platform-tools).  Open the sdk folder and there is the platform tools folder.
4. Paste the downloaded apks to the platform tools folder
5. Press Shift and right click the mouse, then press "Open command windows here"
6. In the cmd type adb devices and hit enter. Then your will use "adb install name_of_the_each_apk" for each of the three apks.
7. Open the google play and enter your account, and follow the steps: next, install google play services, open maps, and so on, they will guide you. That's all.

AS SIMPLE AS THAT.

Comment: Yes genymotion is definitely a good idea. More information about this question ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu

Answer (score 0):

I got finally map in my emulator. I followed these steps to achieve it.

1. Create avd and start emulator
2. Go to platform tools path present in Android SDK and put these apk's in it.

   - com.android.vending-20130716
   - com.google.android.gms-20130716
3. Install these apk's one by one by going to platform tools path by using command prompt(shift+Right click-->open command window here).Follow these commands

   - adb devices
   - adb install com.android.vending-20130716
   - adb install com.google.android.gms-20130716
4. Import google-play-services_lib project which is present at project location and add it to your project.
5. Restart emulator and clean your project and run it through emulator.

That's it. :)
you can download above apk's from following link

[Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator)

[image]