# error with google map v2

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

i am trying to display or see google maps on my app.

1. I have added the library google_play_services_lib(no error).
2. Obtain a google maps api key.
3. Follow the code in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#overview_intro
   (no error).
4. But run the app in emulator, it stopped. it says "Unfortunately ShowMapActivity has stopped ".

i am not getting any error. i think problem is in xml file.fragment is not working. what should i do now. plz help me with this or give me simple sample project using google map. i am beginner at google map in  android and trying badly to fix it but......:(

here is the activity_main.xml file :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java file :

```
    package com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;  
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    /*map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
    .getMap();
    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
    .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(KIEL)
    .title("Kiel")
    .snippet("Kiel is cool")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    */  }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }
    }
```

and AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission  android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyADyrVyRG68lvuQ0721D_Iaw0VLaeMjNuA"
        android:value="AIzaSyADyrVyRG68lvuQ0721D_Iaw0VLaeMjNuA" />
</application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: You can try the code from http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/06/25/android-google-maps-api-v2/, it explains all the steps.

Comment: alex is right, i made 3 apps using Google Map and if you still find problem ask me on this [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17407246#17407246)

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094787/map-not-getting-in-emulator-android-api-v2/19317114#19317114

Comment: please post your Logcat..

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `meta-data` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file with this one.

`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyADyrVyRG68lvuQ0721D_Iaw0VLaeMjNuA" />`

also add this `meta-data` too.

`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Hope this will solve your problems.

Comment: As @Kaushik said you need to use the real device to test it properly

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly you have to run the application in a **real device** not in **emulator**. Emulator does not have `google play service` installed if you don't have any real device try to run your application in `Genymotion's emulator` after installing `google play service`.

You can check [Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-the-android-emulator)

you need to change

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyADyrVyRG68lvuQ0721D_Iaw0VLaeMjNuA" />
```

add this inside `application tag`

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my map fragment as a reference. You can add the missing attributes and see if it's working.

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    map:cameraZoom="11" />
```