# Google map API v2. android

Tags: android, xml, api, dictionary

I'm trying to develop an android app where it shows my current location on google map , but I'm having difficulties on showing the map on emulator. I've been working with this since yesterday and I tried looking for solution by browsing similar thread but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

here is my logcat:

```
    07-24 03:35:27.041: I/dalvikvm(1268): Could not find method 

    android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a
    07-24 03:35:27.041: W/dalvikvm(1268): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 145: Landroid/app/AlertDialog$Builder;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;I)V
    07-24 03:35:27.041: D/dalvikvm(1268): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x002c
    07-24 03:35:27.051: I/dalvikvm(1268): Could not find method android.app.Activity.getFragmentManager, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b
    07-24 03:35:27.051: W/dalvikvm(1268): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 94: Landroid/app/Activity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
    07-24 03:35:27.051: D/dalvikvm(1268): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0023
    07-24 03:35:27.051: D/dalvikvm(1268): VFY: dead code 0x0026-0030 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (ILandroid/app/Activity;Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;ILandroid/content/DialogInterface$OnCancelListener;)Z
    07-24 03:35:27.061: D/dalvikvm(1268): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
    07-24 03:35:27.061: W/dalvikvm(1268): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 60
    07-24 03:35:27.061: D/dalvikvm(1268): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
    07-24 03:35:27.061: D/dalvikvm(1268): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
    07-24 03:35:27.081: D/AndroidRuntime(1268): Shutting down VM
    07-24 03:35:27.081: W/dalvikvm(1268): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb5f054f0)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapdemo/com.example.googlemapdemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:128)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.example.googlemapdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     ... 11 more
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5077000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.x(Unknown Source)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.F(Unknown Source)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.E(Unknown Source)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.ju(Unknown Source)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
    07-24 03:35:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     ... 19 more
```

here is my
activity_main.xml

```
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

GoogleMapDemo.manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemapdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
<permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAMQ0-kK-KaFM_SeGjn7Nv22WvETNRmRZc"
           />         
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Google Maps API is not available on the emulator, afaik.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, why not we can get map in emulator too see my answer

Comment: @user3796244 Did you got the map??

Comment: nope but I know now the error . my Android emulator doesn't connect to the internet thats why I cant run my google map. Now I'm trying to fix this specific error ( warning: No DNS server found)

Answer (score 1):

Use google api 19 version emulator while creating the AVD in your Eclipse IDE.

Maps is available in google api emulator only. If the problem persist again, update the SDK of your emulator to latest build and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Yes., you can get map in emulator too. To achieve this follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094787/map-not-getting-in-emulator-android-api-v2/19317114#19317114) step by step process which I answered in another post

Comment: Installing APKs from an unknown source is dangerous.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice But we can get map in emulator also naa? The OP wants map in emulator so I given solution for that. why you down voted it??

Answer (score -1):

In your manifest :
 meta-data
 must be outside application block
and you have to add :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version>     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Comment: <meta-data/> is not allowed outside of <application/>