# Google play services are missing from your phone

Tags: android

I am trying to compile the sample code on еclipse from https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html, I installed Google Play services, follow steps http://developer.android.com/google/ play-services/setup.html # Setup  and received the following error: This application will not run without Google Play services that are missing from your phone.How to fix the problem?

Comment: your phone doesnot have google settings app.

Comment: Do you have a custom ROM on your phone? If not - which version of Android is it?
Or if you're using an emulator - which emulator is it?

Comment: Download Google Play Services from the Play Store.  If your phone doesn't have the play store-  your options are pirate it or don't use it.

Comment: I used emulator: Device: Galaxi Nexus 4.65", 720x 1280:xhdpi, Target: Google APIs(Google Inc.)- API level 17,Platform: 4.2.2

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094787/map-not-getting-in-emulator-android-api-v2/19317114#19317114

Answer (score 0):

In order to test Google Play Services on an emulator, I'd suggest doing the following:

1. Obtain the [Genymotion emulator](https://cloud.genymotion.com/) (it has a free version). This emulator is way faster and easy to work with than the stock SDK one.
2. Download a "Google apps' (*gapps*) package. Example sources: [source1](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps), [source2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2397942).
3. After installing the emulator, setting up a virtual device and starting it, simply drag-and-drop the gapps zip into the running device window. You will see a "Filte transfer in progress" dialog, followed by this dialog:

[image: gapps install confirmation dialog]

Then you need to click `OK`, at which point you will get the following confirmation:
[image: flashing successful dialog]

Now just reboot the virtual device, and you'll have gapps installed. 
Also note that you need to enable the GPS once the virtual device has booted, using the button on the right of the interface:
[image: GPS button in Genymotion]

This procedure will get you **very** close to a real device.