# Google Play Services in Genymotion on Lollipop (Android 5.0)

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-5.0-lollipop, genymotion

Can't seem to find any mention of support of Google Play services on Android 5.0 API 21 (Lollipop) in what seems like the [canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt) thread on the subject or google. Does anyone have any insight on this?

I'm familiar with the practice of downloading the gapps package and installing, have it working on Kitkat and Jellybean just fine. Both of those install packages seem to hose the VM if I try them on 5.0

With the recent Genymotion upgrades I was hoping they'd be beefing up for compatibility, but I can't seem to find any hints.

Comment: out of curiosity: do you have genymotion 5 (lollipop) working?  mine freezes at boot time....  :(

Comment: I do! It took a very long time to boot the first time around, but logcat was alive so I let it run, eventually it came up.

Comment: strange, i was waiting more then half an hour,  it passed "upgrading  72 applications" phase but didn't boot completely... maybe RAM issue?  mine is 4 GB

Comment: Hmm not sure, maybe try recreating the VM? My host machine has 8GB but i've only got 2 allocated to the instance

Comment: thanks for input,  i already did it twice or more,  even upgraded to the latest genymotion 2.3.1, still no luck,  i think i will wait for a official release

Comment: I just got mine to boot after I restarted my computer. Took about 2 minutes, but I'm also running on 16GB ram.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can download the Google Apps for Android 5.0 (Lollipop) from this URL https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559 as instructed [here](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145) (Genymotion with Google Play Services).
I already have them working on the Genymotion "Lollipop Preview - Nexus 5" device.

Comment: I'm using genymotion 2.3.7 and I just installed google nexus 4-5.0.0 api 21 , and I couldn't install arm translation 1.1 , after drag and drop I got "Failed to flash file Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip"

Comment: I think the last known version of genymotion is 2.3.1 (not 2.3.7), so after I downloaded the virtual device "Google Nexus 4 - 5.0.0 - API 21", I flashed the "Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip" and after that the "gapps-lp-20141109-signed.zip" (as instructed) and it is working as expected. Maybe you need to delete the virtual device of yours and start all over again with these steps.

Comment: What does it mean to *flash* a file? I drag the ARM dmg file into the VM, it shows a loading bar briefly, and then is says "file successfully copied to..." Is that what it's supposed to be?

Comment: It means to Drag&Drop a file (in our case, the Genymotion-ARM-Translation.zip) onto the Genymotion VM window. Once you do this, it should say "File transfer in progress", and then click 'OK' when it asks you to flash it to the virtual device.

Comment: If Google Now keeps crashing on you, just sign into Google play and update all the apps (which should pull down the latest Google Play Services).

Comment: The solution worked fine for me, but had to restart the emulator several times and wait for the play services to update "on the background" (with a white screen been the only output I had as reference).

Answer (score 2):

first: dowload [ARM Translation](http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv) and gapps [Android 5.0.x](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559) or [Android 4.4](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95832962473395379).x or  [Android 4.3.x](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124) etc

second: drop&drop ARM Translation file in your emulator

third: reboot adb `./adb reboot`

fourth: drop&drop gapps file in your emulator

fifth: reboot adb `./adb reboot`

[here](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en) more information

**good luck**

Answer (score 0):

For Android 5.1 and 5.1.1, I've found a better version [here](http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/gapps/5.1/gapps-L-4-21-15.zip). 
The `androidfilehost.com` wasn't working at this time.