# error after flashing genymotion with google play (Google+ error)

Tags: genymotion

I flashed my genymotion device and after, I got this error.

"An error occurred during the installation of google+ Please uninstall the app and then install it again"

To elaborate.

I created a new device, this one at the top highlgihted.

Google Nexus 4 5.0.0 API 21

[image]

I read this good and (as of writing), up to date answer here about installing google play services on it [Google Play Services in Genymotion on Lollipop (Android 5.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045599/google-play-services-in-genymotion-on-lollipop-android-5-0)

So I started it, did `adb devices` saw the device listed there.

Dragged this on Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip

I did `adb reboot`

I dragged this on gapps-lp-20141109-signed.zip

I did `adb reboot`

Then I got this screen (it looked good though I knew it might not work so I took a screenshot as "evidence"!)

[image]

Then on going to google play store, or on unlocking the screen.. and periodically..or whenever it is, I got/get this screen

[image]

It did ask me to register with google signing or or creating a new account when going into the play store, and I did. Though I still get that google+ error message from time to time.

I can use android studio's emulator api 21 in the meantime as while it doesn't have google play store, it does seem to have google play services such that various apps can run, but i'd be interested in having genymotion running without error with google apps services too, particularly as having the google play store, as it does, is good so if it can be without this error then all the better.

Answer (score 11):

You need to be patient through the error messages, and manage to sign-in to the play store and update Google+.
After, you should get a notification saying you need to update `Google Play Services`, do it as well.

It can be annoying with the error message popping all the time but you just have to go through this once :).
Reboot the device after and it should work.