# Google Play services out of date. Requires 4030500 but found 3265136

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I am new to android.Recently,I'm using the Google maps v2 in my app and am debugging it in the emulator.I get the message from Logcat like this:

Google Play services out of date. Requires 4030500 but found 3265136.

Where can I find the updated apk (Google Play Services, revision 13) (gms and vending),Can U help me ?

Answer (score 0):

i think your google play service version API 14 but in your mobile or emuulator has lower version like 12 or lower than 14
you are sdk google play is higher than you device or emulator.
you can solve in two ways,

1.you can use lower googlepay service in your project as library project.
2.else you have to upgrade you google play service in you device or emuulator

Answer (score -1):

Same problem, fixing one problem leads to another problem, struggling for weeks with this.
Try these and see if it works out

[Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator)

[This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services (via Bazaar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13869332#13869332)

and many more are there.