# android : google map working in tablet not in vmware why?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

i'm a novice in Android, and i have a Project on google maps api in android, so i followed the officiel site tutorial(step by step) to how to draw a map app. 
off course i had really big problem with eclipse default emulator(too slow) so i installed android in my vmware it's working fine, but **the app is showing a black map with google signature and the zoom in and zoom out buttons**, but when i tested it in a friend tablet it worked just fine.
if anyone can help i'll be greatful.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapexemple"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapexample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" /> 

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapexample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="key" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapexemple.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity_main.xml:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lng"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:ems="10" android:inputType="text">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
         android:layout_below="@+id/map"     
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lng"
        android:ems="10"  android:inputType="text"
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/find" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.mapexemple;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.example.mapexemple.R;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

SupportMapFragment mMap;
GoogleMap googleMap;
Button btn;
EditText lngg;
EditText latt;
static final LatLng CasaVoyageur = new LatLng(33.589509,-7.590633);
private LatLng destination = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
     lngg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lng);
     latt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lat);
    mMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = mMap.getMap();

     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



@Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
         destination=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lngg.getText().toString()),Double.parseDouble(latt.getText().toString())
        );
     googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
     destination, 18));
     googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));
     System.out.println(destination.latitude);
     System.out.println(destination.longitude);
     }
         })
}
}
```

Comment: i took the google play services project and i linked it to my app project as the tutorial said, and i installed googple play in my (android)vmware also, but is it explicitly for v2 i don't know !!!

Comment: looks like there is some problem with authentication, what you can try , see the logcat for possible errors, also, uninstall the app from vmware player, clean and rebuild your project and install it.

Comment: In your manifest file `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="key" />` key must be api-key that you generate?

Comment: yes exactly based on sha1 debug key + package.i followed the steps one by one i don't think that would be the reason.

Comment: So, pls check the link on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not run google-maps on emulator or virtual device. Found on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator)

Comment: that is going to be serious probleme for me, i realy can't afford to by an android phone or tablet.i don't know if you heard of genymotion emulator my cooworkers says that is working fine but the problem is my CPU dosn't support virtualisation.

Comment: i read about genymotion and used it for a short moment. It is better than android emulator and people says that the genymotion supports google-maps but I never tried. Finally again it is not possible for emulator unfortunately.