# Working with Google Maps on android emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I want to run my app on emulator(4.0.3).
So i have followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13869332#13869332)

I have been successfly installed 3 apk but when i try to install GoogleLoginService.apk or GoogleServiceFramwork.apk : the cmd show this error "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES"

thanx and excuse me for this bad english!

Comment: see this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/q/14040185/1979347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out GenyMotion. It works great. Just download the gapps zip from Cyanogemod and install it on the emulator to get the play store and all the other google services.

http://www.genymotion.com/