# Trouble using Google sign-in button in the emulator

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

When I click the Google sign-in button, it shows the following dialog.

[image]

I click on Update and nothing happens, but my logcat gives the following output.

```
01-24 07:38:48.121: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1305): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4132500 but found 4033530
01-24 07:38:50.321: E/SettingsRedirect(1305): Can't redirect to app settings for Google Play services
```

How can I get this to work on my emulator?

After it failed I ran the following command to see the error and got the following output:

```
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -d -s Packag
eManager:*
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
W/PackageManager(  390): Running ENG build: no pre-dexopt!
D/PackageManager(  390): No files in app dir /vendor/app
W/PackageManager(  390): Package com.example.android.apis desires unavailable sh
ared library com.example.will.never.exist; ignoring!
W/PackageManager(  390): Package com.example.android.apis desires unavailable sh
ared library com.example.will.never.exist; ignoring!
I/PackageManager(  390): Time to scan packages: 5.417 seconds
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARC
H to package com.android.quicksearchbox (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be45)
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.smspush.WAPPUSH_MANAGER_
BIND in package com.android.phone
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.vending.billing.BILLING_
ACCOUNT_SERVICE in package com.google.android.gsf.login
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.vending.billing.ADD_CRED
IT_CARD in package com.google.android.gsf.login
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.vending.billing.IBilling
AccountService.BIND2 in package com.google.android.gsf.login
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.vending.TOS_ACKED in pac
kage com.google.android.gsf.login
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.chrome.TOS_ACKED in pack
age com.google.android.gsf.login
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNL
OAD_MANAGER to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x9be45)
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOA
D_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9b
e45)
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDG
ET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be44)
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission android.permission.INSTALL_DRM in pa
ckage com.android.mms
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.DELETE_PACKA
GES to package com.svox.pico (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be45)
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER
 to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x48be45)
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.READ_DREAM_S
TATE to package com.google.android.gsf (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x40083e45)
I/PackageManager(  390): No secure containers on sdcard
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARC
H to package com.android.quicksearchbox (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be45)
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.smspush.WAPPUSH_MANAGER_
BIND in package com.android.phone
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.vending.billing.BILLING_
ACCOUNT_SERVICE in package com.google.android.gsf.login
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.vending.billing.ADD_CRED
IT_CARD in package com.google.android.gsf.login
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.vending.billing.IBilling
AccountService.BIND2 in package com.google.android.gsf.login
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.vending.TOS_ACKED in pac
kage com.google.android.gsf.login
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission com.android.chrome.TOS_ACKED in pack
age com.google.android.gsf.login
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNL
OAD_MANAGER to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x9be45)
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOA
D_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9b
e45)
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDG
ET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be44)
W/PackageManager(  390): Unknown permission android.permission.INSTALL_DRM in pa
ckage com.android.mms
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.DELETE_PACKA
GES to package com.svox.pico (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be45)
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER
 to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x48be45)
W/PackageManager(  390): Not granting permission android.permission.READ_DREAM_S
TATE to package com.google.android.gsf (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x40083e45)
I/PackageManager(  390):   Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
I/PackageManager(  390):   Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
I/PackageManager(  390):   Scheme: "sms"
I/PackageManager(  390): Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms
/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
I/PackageManager(  390):   Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
I/PackageManager(  390):   Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
I/PackageManager(  390):   Scheme: "smsto"
I/PackageManager(  390): Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms
/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
I/PackageManager(  390):   Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
I/PackageManager(  390):   Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
I/PackageManager(  390):   Scheme: "mms"
I/PackageManager(  390): Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms
/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
I/PackageManager(  390):   Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
I/PackageManager(  390):   Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
I/PackageManager(  390):   Scheme: "mmsto"
I/PackageManager(  390): Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms
/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
W/PackageManager(  390): Attempt to delete unknown system package com.android.ve
nding
W/PackageManager(  390): Attempt to delete unknown system package com.android.ve
nding
W/PackageManager(  390): Attempt to delete unknown system package com.google.and
roid.gms

C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\platform-tools>
```

What am I supposed to make of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on the page *[How to install Google Maps v2 in Android Emulator](http://hintdesk.com/how-to-install-google-maps-in-android-emulator-and-use-it-in-intellij-idea/)*.

It only works with Android 4.22, but I think that the same idea can be applied to version 4.4 with the appropriate files.

1. Download the three files listed on the previous page: com.android.vending-19032013.apk,  com.google.android.gms-19032013.apk and Google play services lib r5.
2. Create an AVD device with a normal target (Android 4.22, API 17), with Intel Atom (x86) if you want to use.
3. Install the two [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) files from Android console.
4. Create your app for Android 4.22
5. DO NOT USE the google-play-services-lib of your system. You must use the third downloaded file.

Answer (score 2):

The emulator does not support the `Google Play Services`. That is why it's throwing an error. To develop using the APIs, you need to provide a development device such as an Android phone or tablet.

> `Google Play services out of date.Requires 4132500 but found 4033530`

To get the play services in your emulator, you have to install the APK file on your own.

Here are the APK [gms](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nhea18k7ic2gpb/com.google.android.gms-20130716.apk) and [vending](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hznsfc03shud2l9/com.android.vending-20130716.apk) files.

Install both the APK files using the below command.

```
adb install com.android.vending-20130716.apk 
adb install com.google.android.gms-20130716.apk
```

And if it's already installed then to upgrade an existing emulator, you need to uninstall the previous versions using the below command and then install it again:

```
adb uninstall com.android.vending
adb uninstall com.google.android.gms
```

Comment: WHere do I save the apk files?

Comment: copy that in your `android-sdk/platform-tools` folder and install it using the commands which i have specified in my answer.

Comment: They were already installed so I went to uninstall them by using your last commands but it just says **Failure**, thats all.

Comment: I checked the error message with adb logcat -d -s PackageManager:*, please see my edit. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Clay Its saying that you do not have permission to uninstall playstore application. I suggest you to just install the apk again and it will override to the old one.

Comment: Yeah I want to install the apk again but it says they're already installed so I have to uninstall them but then I get the error message saying I dont have permission. So how am I supposed to install it?