# Need apk for Google Play services with version 4132500

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adb, google-play-services

I have an app that is making use of the latest google play services sdk.
The emulators don't seem to come with the latest pre installed, and the 'update' link that pops up during the version check, does not respond.

There are lots of similar questions around these issues, and they all have the same answer, where the apk needs to be installed manually (ie. http://hintdesk.com/how-to-install-google-maps-in-android-emulator-and-use-it-in-intellij-idea/).

However it seems all these other pages refer to older apk versions. I'm using platform v. 4.4.2, API level 19. using 4.4.2 emulator, and getting this exact version error: "Google Play services out of date.Requires 4132500 but found 4033530"

I have tried 2 different sets of vendor and gms apks. ones with date 19032013, and ones with date 20130716

These resulted in the same error but an even older version found: 
"Google Play services out of date.Requires 4132500 but found 3025110" 
"Google Play services out of date.Requires 4132500 but found 3159132"

BTW, I was also getting the "Failure" issue when trying to uninstall the apks using adb.. I switched to the non API emulator, and was able to uninstall / install other apks.
The "failure" issue is mentioned in the comments of:
[Trouble using Google sign-in button in the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333069/trouble-using-google-sign-in-button-in-emulator/21396213#21396213)

I think it's just a matter of using those common steps, but we need newer apk files. How do we get a hold of the ones for version 4132500 ? 
I don't want to use the older sdk.. and I don't want to use my real device.. I really need to get the emulator working on the latest sdk.
Does anyone have a line on version 4132500 apks? Or does someone know another way to update google play services on the emulator?

Comment: I've heard the adb uninstall only works on non google API emulators.  So.. i guess the other option is to find a version of the SDK, that aligns with the API 19 emulator (has google play services version 4033530). I'm using the latest sdk (rev 14).. so maybe I should try and find sdk rev 13 to work with this emulator?

Comment: Hey that's my question :) I really need an answer I can't even continue developing my app.

Comment: got the work around working.. so i altered my project to use an older SDK. Couldn't find a quick way to 'downgrade' to rev 13, so I tried out the google play services "for froyo" sdk.  I installed that and referenced it as a library for my project rather then the rev 14 one. It worked great - no version complaint.  Thanks to this thread: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61675  for having the blunt note at the bottom that this would work.  I believe this proves google needs to release a new Google API emulator version for the 4132500 version of play services.

Comment: though.. i did have to comment out <!--      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" -->
<!--            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> -->
 in the manifest as it didn't seem to find the version reference.. maybe its just working because of that..

Comment: @Clay.. yeah.. I was trying to add these details to your Q, but a moderator kept deleting them.. so had to add my own! if you think your app can get by using hte older sdk, that should at least let you continue coding until Google releases a new Google API emulator platform.. if i understand all this right!