# Exception of google maps in my android application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I did all steps to show Google maps in android.

I have downloaded the newest version of Google play services , but still  I have the below exceptions :

```
07-18 05:25:36.319: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:36.389: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:36.389: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:36.489: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:36.529: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:36.559: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:36.629: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:36.709: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:36.769: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:36.949: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:36.989: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2054): Google Play services is missing.
07-18 05:25:40.239: I/Choreographer(2054): Skipped 494 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-18 05:25:44.689: D/gralloc_goldfish(2054): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-18 05:25:55.930: D/AndroidRuntime(2054): Shutting down VM
07-18 05:25:55.930: W/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1f58648)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-18 05:25:56.010: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 05:26:02.570: I/Process(2054): Sending signal. PID: 2054 SIG: 9
```

this is the manifest of my app i have added permisions and the api key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tunivote"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <permission android:name="com.example.tunivote.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.tunivote.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="com.example.tunivote.providres.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                   android:value="my api key" />
         <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="authentification"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you testing on emulator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-the-android-emulator have a look on this **At the moment, referencing the Google Android Map API v2 you can't run Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator; you must use a device for your tests.**

Comment: yes i am testing on emulator

Answer (score 0):

Once check your emulator type, Whether it is Android or Google emulator. Please make sure your running on Google API  Emulator.