# Unfortunately google maps has stopped

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I would get google map on my emulator.
I followed the instructions on 
When I run the application an error's message appears:Unfortunately DemoGoogleMapsV2 has stopped.

my androidmanifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission android:name="com.demogooglemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.demogooglemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
Google Maps Android API, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="API_KEY"/>

<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

my activity_main.xml:

```
<android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

my MainActivity.java:

```
 package com.demogooglemapsv2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

the log error:

> 09-04 17:43:51.170: E/Trace(1477): error opening trace file: No such
>   file or directory (2) 09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.demogooglemapsv2/com.demogooglemapsv2.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error
>   inflating class fragment 09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-04 17:43:53.449:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-04 17:43:53.449:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-04 17:43:53.449:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1477): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   com.demogooglemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   ... 11 more 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
>   AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000
>   but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the
>    element:      09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown
>   Source) 09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.I(Unknown Source) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.H(Unknown Source) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.jz(Unknown Source)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source) 09-04 17:43:53.449:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source) 09-04
>   17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown
>   Source) 09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
>   09-04 17:43:53.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):   ... 21 more

Comment: Show your full log of the error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-the-android-emulator

Comment: API_KEY in Manifest isn't filled in too

Comment: I fill the API_Key but I can't show it to the public

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar: I aded the google_paly_service to my project

Comment: google play lib work when play store app are avaliable on your device like emulater

Comment: Show your logcat  error

Comment: I don't think it works on an emulator, only on real devices...

Comment: you can run Google map on [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator

Answer (score 0):

Replace FragmentActivity in place of Activity, make sure you are entering right api key.

And in place of 
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
use
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Make sure google play services is installed on your device. That's why try to run the application on real device not on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment  
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this tag in your menifest file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope your project and `google-play-services_lib` both are in same `workspace` and you have added it as `library` project in your application. If your `API-Key` is ok then you need to change like this.

1.  add this `meta-data` inside `application` tag in `manifest`

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

2. As `minSdkVersion="8"` you should use `SupportMapFragment` so `activity_main.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

3.  Instead of `Activity` you should extend `FragmentActivity` and use `SupportFragmentManager()`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
      GoogleMap mMap = fm.getMap(); 
  }
}
```

> Try to run it on real device or Genymotion's emulator after installing
>   google-play-service. Otherwise you will face a crash