# App initialization very slow: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321728/firebaseinitprovider-firebaseapp-initialization-unsuccessful) but I don't think it helps me and the problem looks slightly different.

I'm doing this app where I need to implement AppsFlyer for tracking and I'm required to use only 2 components from Google Play Services:

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads
>
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm

And I'm using the latest version of the Google Play Services, 9.0.2 that is.

The problem is that **on the first app launch after installing the app**, the app takes quite a bit of time to start. There's no log output and when the app starts doing something, the first line on the log is:

> 06-16 16:50:23.782 22368-22368/com.company.app I/FirebaseInitProvider:
> FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

I'm not using Firebase, how can I get rid of this? It really slows down the application initialization. Not a very good user experience...

**EDIT:**

I've added both libs, one at a time and I've realized that the GCM is the one causing the issue. When I add:

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm

I start getting the "FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful" log and the app takes a while to start. Perhaps downgrading "fixes" the problem, but that's not a very good solution.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet? Also check if you have any firebase dependencies in your app.

Comment: @abielita There's no code... I just include those 2 dependencies on the app's `build.gradle` file. And I don't have any Firebase dependencies. This problem started with the inclusion of those Play Services dependencies.

Comment: AppsFlyer are not using Firebase. Do you have FirebaseInitProvider on your manifest?

Comment: @gmeroz No, I don't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest you to exclude the `firebase` group using `gradle`:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-common'
}

compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-common'
}
```

Or, simply apply a global exclude configuration, like this:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-common'
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: After some testing, this **fixes the problem for me**. The " FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful" log message never occurs and there's no slow startup. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and not only I had to downgrade the services but also gradle version.

In my case I had (in app/build.gradle)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
```

and (in build.gradle)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

After changing services back to 8.4.0 and gradle to 1.5.0 (Probably higher version is fine also but it was the one I had before upgrading to 2.1.2) everything is fine and FirebaseApp initialization is gone.

Maybe it's not the best solution but I couldn't find anything else.