# FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

Try using firebase library for Android, followed all the steps in the firebase documents, when I apply the instructions show me in logcat

> FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful.

**Images**

[image: Image_1]

[image: Image-2]

> Who can help , please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in [The Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/gradle/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">1035469437078-e8mr503bun5eaevqctn4u807q4hpi44s.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">1035469437078</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">https://myapp.firebaseio.com</string>
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:1035469437078:android:73a4fb8297b2cd4f</string>
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">AIzaSyFE3G2eN0XZPl-IeEvZhzKOAgC9vy9imVE</string>
    <string name="google_storage_bucket" translatable="false">myapp.appspot.com</string>
</resources>
```

**gcm_defaultSenderId:**

project_info/project_number

**google_app_id:**

{YOUR_CLIENT}/client_info/mobilesdk_app_id

**google_api_key:**

{YOUR_CLIENT}/services/api_key/current_key

**google_storage_bucket:**

project_info/storage_bucket

**firebase_database_url:**

project_info/firebase_url

**default_web_client_id:**

{YOUR_CLIENT}/oauth_client/[first client_type 3]

Comment: Can you please double-check the link? It appears to be broken. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've already inserting google-services-json inside **app** folder and you have stable internet connection, firebase will perform download package when gradle sync process.

Comment: Yes, I put google-servers.json file in app folder , but also Not solved

Comment: @Omar see my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37901548/549372 ...and maybe next time use the search function before creating duplicate questions.