# android FCM with gradle experimental gives 'FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful'

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, gradle-experimental

I am using a gradle experimental in my project.And have some native c/c++ code.
I made a normal project without any c/c++ code and implemented FCM it worked properly and give an fcm token .

But when i am using gradle experimental i.e **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.3'**
it gives 'FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful'
Any help would be appreciated.

```
enter code here


apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId "example.app"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel 15
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }
    buildTypes {


        debug{
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
        }
        release {

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard  true
            proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.config")
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    ndk {
        moduleName "native"
    }


}

android.dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize = "4g"
}

}
```

}

```
 dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 compile files('libs/gson-2.3.jar')

 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

 compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
 compile 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'




 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: See this -http://stackoverflow.com/a/37901548/6291914

Comment: i have seen the above link and tried but could not get success . I think it because of the gradle experimental i am getting 'FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful' . I have the used the same process of FCm with my backup project which used normal gradle and did not had any c/c++ source  code and it run perfectly.