# Fetch Google place with a placeId

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I want to make a marker on a Google Map on a specific place, the only information that I have is it's *Google Places ID*.

Retrieving the necessary information could be achieved with the command `getPlaceById()` according to [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) but that doesn't seem to work for me.

**This is the code I use to request the place**

```
private void addMarkerById(String id){
    android.util.Log.d("MAP", "Finding place for " + id);

    Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mClient, id) .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (places.getStatus().isSuccess() && places.getCount() > 0) {
                Place place = places.get(0);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.getLatLng()).title(place.getName().toString()));
            }
            places.release();
        }
    });
}
```

The map itself works fine and manually adding `LatLng` also works. 
The problem is probably with `onResult` which doesn't seem to run at all.

**The logs**

```
05-17 19:51:52.940 2358-2358/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-17 19:51:52.940 2358-2358/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-17 19:51:53.404 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal-1/lib/x86
05-17 19:51:53.430 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
05-17 19:51:53.431 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-17 19:51:53.556 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal I/zzai: Making Creator dynamically
05-17 19:51:53.559 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
05-17 19:51:53.560 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/system/fake-libs:/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/system/lib:/vendor/lib for namespace 0xb3ace090
05-17 19:51:53.769 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
05-17 19:51:53.770 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
05-17 19:51:53.770 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/system/fake-libs:/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/system/lib:/vendor/lib for namespace 0xb3ace0d0
05-17 19:51:53.872 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/n/x86
05-17 19:51:54.008 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 10240000
05-17 19:51:54.068 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 10298470
05-17 19:51:54.290 2358-2428/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
05-17 19:51:54.437 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal D/MAP: Locations Executed
05-17 19:51:54.485 2358-2358/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal D/MAP: Finding place for ChIJ5zmn4oo4w0cRUGpTw9AkU0A

                                                                 [ 05-17 19:51:54.512  2358: 2469 D/         ]
                                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa41c5580, tid 2469
05-17 19:51:54.514 2358-2469/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-17 19:51:54.514 2358-2469/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
05-17 19:51:54.514 2358-2469/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
05-17 19:51:54.514 2358-2469/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
05-17 19:51:55.077 2358-2365/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.665ms
05-17 19:51:56.408 2358-2462/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
05-17 19:51:56.416 2358-2462/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2
05-17 19:51:56.416 2358-2462/be.gillescoeman.scubajournal I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 2
```

Comment: Any errors in the logs?

Comment: No clear error was shown in the logs. I've added the full log to the question.

Comment: Looks like Firebase is not initialized for some reason, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321728/firebaseinitprovider-firebaseapp-initialization-unsuccessful

Comment: @DanielNugent I've fixed the Firebase issue, but the rest of the log remains the same. The `onResult` still doesn't run.

`05-18 07:08:02.737 23723-23723/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful`

Answer (score 0):

Your `onResult` does nothing if `getStatus().isSuccess()` is false.  Try logging the status, there may be an error.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to fix the issue.

I created a new database table which stores all information I need for the place. This allows me to only use the Places API when entering a new place in the app. Once a place has been added I no longer need the `getPlaceById()`

It is **not a solution**, but it does enable me to continue development.