# Error:(15, 55) error: cannot access zza class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

Here is my build.gradle app file:

```
dependencies {
    //picture library
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    //recycler and card view
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'

    //json
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my build.gradle Project file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am using Firebase Messaging Service, and I want to get notification into my app. So I am just checking the log for any update. My `FirebaseMessagingService` file is:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: "+remoteMessage.getData());

    }
```

While Compiling, I am getting error. How to resolve it?

Comment: why you don't post the whole `build.gradle` and why you use such outdated build-tools??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321728/firebaseinitprovider-firebaseapp-initialization-unsuccessful)

Comment: thanks guys just solved by changing version of firebase-messaging to latest version. But token is not generated as it says 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService' is deprecated,what is alternative method to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the firebase [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), please update your dependencies to the latest versions. So please change the following lines of code:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
```

You can also upgrade the gradle of your project to the latest version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

Comment: this still would need `play-services-base`  & `play-services-auth`, as the error message hints for.

Comment: @MartinZeitler According to OP's requirements, Google Play services dependencies should be added accordingly. This is how the OP can [Set Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

Comment: without the whole `build.gradle` (despite the dependency is completely missing), this is typically is also one of the classes, which can be affected by ProGuard... while it might be true, that only `play-services-base` might be required, meanwhile... the docs there only state `firebase-core`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are Getting this Error:

```
error: cannot access zza class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found
```

Then Use this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'

api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

It Works...

Answer (score 0):

add This

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
```