# Writing data to Firebase from a fragment in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

So, I have a fragment class and I am trying to write data to Firebase Realtime database using the below code in `onCreateView()` method,

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CollectionName");
String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
databaseReference.child(id).setValue(new myModel(param1, param2));
```

After running this code, whenever I try to write data, I am getting below error:

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process <package_name>. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

This error points to the line where I am trying to get the instance from the firebase.

Now, I've tried many things like using below statement in `onCreate()` method,

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MainActivity.getContext());
```

Here, **MainActivity** is the class from where this fragment loads.

Also, I have all the necessary dependencies installed in both my Module level and Project level gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just initialize the Firebase in the `onCreate` function of your `MainActivity` using the following.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

If you want to initialize it from your fragment, you could do this in the `onCreateView` before calling the `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()`.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getActivity());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried to use both the options but it didn't work!

Comment: Strange! Do you see anything in the log saying initialization unsuccessful? If that's the case, you might consider checking this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901548/3145960

Comment: No. There's no log related to FirebaseInitProvider tag

Comment: So, I figured it out that the issue was that I missed out to apply one plugin in Module level gradle file.