# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent - googleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to link an address in a list view item which will allow the location of a tourist attraction to appear on google maps. I am experiencing an error when I do this and the app crashes. In the log, the following error appears:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=google.streetview:cbll=46.414382,10.013988 pkg=com.google.android.apps.maps }

I am using the code which is on the Google developers website but it doesn't seem to work. The code is below:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
mContext.startActivity(mapIntent);
```

I have added the `mContext`as this previously had an error before.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+dlat+","+dlng));
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens when **Google Maps** app is not installed on the device/emulator. You need to install google maps or some other map application.

Try

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
//mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
mContext.startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: I'm running this on a GenyMotion device, should it be on there already?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-the-android-emulator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su