# how to create an avd with google service

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I found a nice official open source project [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched) using material design. `iosched` depends on API 20+, I don`t possess such a real device, so I cloned the source and run the app in an android virtual device with Lollipop. Later on, I found `iosched` also depends on Google service, so I failed to run it on virtual device.

I wonder if I can create an AVD with Google service or I can install google service apk after cteated the avd. I feel confused about it, failed many times after trying.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There're tons of answers on your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784198/missing-google-play-services-from-avd In short: there're few workarounds which could help you to install `Google Services` on `AVD`

Answer (score 1):

From google's own site http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

```
If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory 
for Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, 
and install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform target. 
Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform 
include Google Play services.
```